# Python hangman game for loop

Tags: python

When I guess the letter it keeps applying the letter. for example
say the word is words, then I would guess the letter d, then it would do
ddddd. it uses that letter for the whole word. here is my code.

```
import random
print(" Welcome to the HangMan game!!\n","You will have six guesses to get the answer correct, or you will loose!!!",)

lines = open("../WordsForGames.txt").read() 
line = lines[0:] 
                    #lines 24-28 Randomly generate a word from a text file
words = line.split() 
myword = random.choice(words)
print(myword)


words = myword
fake = '_'*len(myword)
count = 0
print(fake)
guesses = 0
guess = input("Enter a letter you would like to guess: ")
fake = list(fake)  #This will convert fake to a list, so that we can access and change it.

for re in range(0, len(myword)):#For statement to loop over the answer (not really over the answer, but the numerical index of the answer)
    fake[re] = guess    #change the fake to represent that, EACH TIME IT OCCURS
    print(''.join(fake))

if guess != (''.join(fake)):
    print("The letter ", guess,"was in the word. Guess another letter please!")
    guess = input("Enter another letter you would like to guess: ")      
    fake[re] = guess    #change the fake to represent that, EACH TIME IT OCCURS
    print(''.join(fake))
```

Comment: this is what it gives me when I change fake to guess

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Mike's CPT-135 python class\hangManStudent\hangManStudent\src\hangMan.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(''.join(guess))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Answer (score 0):

This part is the culprit:

```
for re in range(0, len(myword)):#For statement to loop over the answer (not really over the answer, but the numerical index of the answer)
    fake[re] = guess    #change the fake to represent that, EACH TIME IT OCCURS
    print(''.join(fake))
```

This code replace every element in `fake` with `guess`

Comment: this what it gives me when I change fake to guess.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Mike's CPT-135 python class\hangManStudent\hangManStudent\src\hangMan.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(''.join(guess))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found